# case when with multiple conditions in mysql

Tags: mysql, case-when, multiple-conditions

```
CASE WHEN (D.BUYQ>0 AND D.SELLQ>0 AND D.series_expiry='2050-01-01') then
 sum(D.stt_INTRA_buy*least(D.buyq,D.SELLQ)*D.buyavg)+sum(D.stt_buy*(D.buyq-least(D.buyq,D.SELLQ))*D.buyavg) 
ELSE
sum(D.stt_buy*D.buyq*D.buyavg) 
 END) as xsttbuy
```

The case condition always held's False and it enters into else even after data being there in the database which satisfies the True condition.

Comment: can you give one dataset example where it should be true but happening false ?

Comment: update your question add  your table scheda .. a proper data sample and the expected  result  ,,

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you mean to be applying your test to each database row, not to each result row.  If so, you need to move the case into the sum:

```
SUM(
    CASE WHEN (D.BUYQ>0 AND D.SELLQ>0 AND D.series_expiry='2050-01-01') THEN
        D.stt_INTRA_buy*LEAST(D.buyq,D.SELLQ)*D.buyavg)+D.stt_buy*(D.buyq-LEAST(D.buyq,D.SELLQ))*D.buyavg 
    ELSE
        D.stt_buy*D.buyq*D.buyavg
    END
) AS xsttbuy
```